# Get client's location through Google Map API

Tags: google-maps, dynamic

I would like to get the client location dynamically through Google Maps API.

Below is my code:

```
/*Call external api dynamically*/
var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=" + api_key + "&callback=loadm";
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

/*function */
function loadm() {
 google.load("maps", "3", {other_params:"sensor=false", "callback" : defmap});
}

function defmap() {

 if(google.loader.ClientLocation){
    alert(google.loader.ClientLocation.latitude+" "+google.loader.ClientLocation.longitude};
}
```

I have tried it, but null values are returned. Is there an error in the code?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you got some syntax error in your `alert` line of code.
Try to close all brackets, this line worked for me:

```
if (google.loader.ClientLocation) {
    alert(google.loader.ClientLocation.latitude+" "+google.loader.ClientLocation.longitude);
};
```

Comment: hi kender, sorry i have left out the closing bracket im the coding part in my question. But it exist in the apps. There's no syntax error in while the app run. But couldn't get client location. It returns null value.

Comment: well, the exact code I pased into a .html file, inside a <script></script> tag, gave me my (approx.) location... Tested with Firefox and Chrome on Linux